# GLSL, interface block

Tags: opengl, glsl

## The Problem:

I'm learning *OpenGL* from http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/index.html tutorial, and I had really hard time getting *Tutorial 13: Geometry Impostors* working (6+ hours), and it is now working after a really minor change in the code that should actually be no-op, and I need your help to find out why does it change anything.

## Explanation - edited:

The problem was that with the unchanged code the fragment shader didn't get correct input from the geometry shader, but with either replacing geometry shader's out *interface block* to separate variables or giving the block an instance name makes the program work fine. But these changes should be no-op.

The problem is probably a name collision.

Like this it doesn't work:

```
in VertexData
{
    vec3 cameraSpherePos;
    float sphereRadius;
} vert[];

out FragData
{
    flat vec3 cameraSpherePos;
    flat float sphereRadius;
    smooth vec2 mapping;
};

void main()
{
     mapping = 
     cameraSpherePos = 
     sphereRadius = 
     EmitVertex();
     /* mapping's value doesn't get to the fragment shader correctly */
}
```

But either giving FragData an instance name like frag, and using frag.mappaing instad of mapping, or using 3 separate variables solves the problem.

Why doesn't it work without an instance name?

Edit: It seems to be a driver issue.

Comment: What hardware are you running this on?

Comment: Program is running #verison 330 on:
Geforce GTS 360M - "3.30 NVIDIA via Cg compiler"

Comment: Hm, more shader and c++ code would help to give a more accurate answer.  In your gs shader are you initializing/setting each member of FragData correct for each vertex iteration, before calling EmitVertex(). Also if you have multiple invocations - make sure you have set the FragData correct.

Comment: I've pasted the shader files. Every member of FragData is set, and that problem should still exist even after the change.
About multiple invocations... afaik it's a 4.x feature.

Comment: Did you try creating instance names for all interface blocks like:
FragData { // .. } gs2fs; And then later:
gs2fs.cameraCornerPos = vec4(vert[0].cameraSpherePos, 1.0);

Comment: That worked.. Giving FragDatas instance name solved it. But I still don't know why doesn't it work w/out instance name

Comment: Maybe your local cameraSpherePos (etc.) does not refer to the interface block. I had a similar problem once: somehow, not using instance names worked on amd cards and did not work for nvidia cards or vice versa - can't remember exactly

Comment: Oh, so its a driver issue, thx, didn't really expect that not I'm cause of this problem

Comment: Reposted it as an answer, so that others may find the solution easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create instance names for all interface blocks like:

```
FragData { /* ... */ } gs2fs;
```

And then:

```
gs2fs.cameraCornerPos = vec4(vert[0].cameraSpherePos, 1.0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Working with GLSL samples often gets tedious due to nasty version problems.

Some general debugging advice:

- verify that you included the proper version tags in your shader source
- verify that your OpenGL Driver actually supports that version by calling `glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION)`
- create means of runtime shader-recompilation (e.g. by assigning that to a key event)
- and FOREMOST: use `glGetShaderInfoLog()` and `glGetProgramInfoLog()`!

Comment: I'm using the #version 330 for my program, which is supported by my GPU. 
Actually I programming in c++ not c, so I use the feature that if the compilation/linking wasn't successful, an exception is thrown with the log message as what(). This makes the code a bit easier to read + I don't have to create a "char logbuffer[2000];" just to be able to call the infolog function.

Comment: Multiple intermediate layers will not help you to isolate the bug, and I doubt that people will be overly inclined to build a framework as thick a this tuts framework just to help you. So try to construct a MINIMAL example that reproduces the assumed "bug" using the GLSL debugging measures I've told you.

Answer (score 2):

The problem actually was with not using the latest driver.

I was running this on linux, and got the latest driver from Ubuntu's package manager: the Nvidia 310-experimental. But even though its experimental, it's rather old. With manually installing the 319 from nvidia's site the code worked fine without any change.

*Moral of the story:*

Always use the latest drivers.